# How to get current zoom level using gmaps.js?

Tags: javascript, gmaps.js

I use this

```
var allMap = new GMaps({
        el: '#map',
        zoom: 14,
        lat: userLat,
        lng: userLng,
        zoom_changed: function(e) {
            alert(allMap.zoom);
        }
    });
```

but I allways get alerted "14". I want to cacth specific zoom level and remove all marker if zoomed to much out. So I want to read the current(changed) zoom level on zoom_changed event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use getZoom() method on map object to return current zoom level.